# Scraping HTML table to UITableView

Tags: html, ios, swift, uitableview

I'm scraping a website with HTML tables on it. Does anyone know a good way to parse the HTML into Swift's UITableView with text between each `<br>` being a cell and the day (ie. "Tuesday November 5") as a section title?

I wish there was a API for this data. What if there were multiple tables like this on the same page (ie "Tuesday November 5", "Wednesday November 6", "Thursday November 7")? Is there a way to generalize this? If you could point me in the right direction with a library, that would be great. I've worked with JQuery in the past, but I'm not so good at it yet. Is there something like Jquery for Swift?

Here's the code I have so far:

```swift
import Foundation
let baseUrl = "<url>"
let url = URL(string: baseUrl)!

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
  guard let data = data else {
    print("data was nil")
    return
  }
  guard let htmlString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
    print("couldn't cast data into String")
    return
  }
  print(htmlString)

    let leftSideString = """
    <h3><strong>Tuesday November 5</strong></h3>
    """
    let rightSideString = """
    <h3><strong>Wednesday November 6</strong></h3>
    """

    guard let leftSideRange = htmlString.range(of: leftSideString)
    else {
      print("couldn't find left range")
      return
    }
    guard
      let rightSideRange = htmlString.range(of: rightSideString)
    else {
      print("couldn't find right range")
      return
    }
    let rangeOfTheData = leftSideRange.lowerBound..<rightSideRange.lowerBound
    let valueWeWantToGrab = htmlString[rangeOfTheData]
    print(valueWeWantToGrab) // prints the follower count: 19093
}
task.resume()
```

Example of what's returned:

```html
<h3><strong>Tuesday November 5</strong></h3>

<table border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"><tbody><tr><td>
<p><strong>Breakfast</strong></p>

    <p><strong>Text0<br />
            Text1<br />
            Text2<br />
            Text3<br />
            Text text Text etc<br />
            blah blah<br />
            blah blah <br />
            blah blah                                   <br />
            blah blah<br />
            blah blah<br />
            blah blah<br />
            blah blah<br />
            blah blah</strong></p>
            </td>
        </tr><tr><td>
            <p><strong>Lunch</strong></p>

            <p><strong>blah blah<br />
            blah blah∆<br />
            blah blah<br />
            blah blah<br />
            blah blah<br />
            blah blah<br />
            blah blah<br />
            blah blah<br />
            blah blah<br />
            blah blah<br />
            blah blah<br />
            blah blah <br />
            blah blah</strong></p>
            </td>
        </tr><tr><td>
            <p><strong>Dinner</strong></p>

            <p><strong>blah blah<br />
            blah blah<br />
            blah blah<br />
            blah blah<br />
            blah blah<br />
            blah blah<br />
            blah blah<br />
            blah blah</strong></p>
            </td>
        </tr></tbody></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Parsing HTML documents is a problem that has been solved by libraries if that is a route you are willing to take. One that I have used with success is [SwiftSoup](https://github.com/scinfu/SwiftSoup)